# Change the answer highlighting scheme in the question list (with pictures)

Tags: feature-request, android-app, question-lists

Currently, the Android app highlights questions in the question list by the following rules:

- No highlight: No answers.
- Minimal highlight: At least one answer.
- Full highlight: At least one upvoted answer.

On the regular site, the highlighting rules are different, and allow us to actually see when there have been accepted answers:

- No highlight: No answers.
- Minimal highlight: At least one upvoted answer.
- Full highlight: An accepted answer.

This comparison should make the difference fairly clear:

[image: the two styles compared]
<sup>(due to time difference between these screenshots, the top question received some answers, as you might have noticed)</sup>

### This needs to change

For a few reasons:

- It's inconsistent with the main site, so it's a little confusing.
- *Almost everything* gets full highlighting in the Android app - unless it's received no attention.
- There's no way to tell whether an answer's been accepted for that question, which is significant information.

### How about this?

We could apply the app styles only *slightly differently* to make it consistent with the site.

- No highlight: No answers.
- Minimal highlight: At least one upvoted answer. This would mean **a green background, green answer count and hollow green answer icon.**
- Full highlight: An accepted answer. This would mean **a green background and filled answer icon.**

Here's how these styles would look:

[image: no answers] [image: some answers] [image: accepted answer]

And the question lists would look more like this instead:

[image: a more consistent comparison]

Comment: +1. The iOS app is the same way. Maybe add that tag too?

Comment: @mhlester If that's the case, I'd be comfortable with that if I could supply some iOS mockups too.

Comment: This was changed as of version 1.0.16 (released a couple hours ago) to *only* do the green highlighting of the background if it has an accepted answer, were you testing against a version older than this when making this feature request?

Comment: @Kasra Yes, seems that way! I'm running 1.0.15. I'll update when I can.

Comment: @Jonathan aha, I think the "at least one upvoted answer" criteria isn't being used on the app at the moment but I don't know if it should be.

Comment: @Kasra I just updated; this is a big improvement. Is there some way to mark this suggestion as no longer applicable?

Comment: @Jonathan yep! There's a close reason for "obsolete" questions. Sorry for making you go through the trouble of writing a great request for no reason.

Comment: @Kasra I'm pretty happy you implemented something like this this so quickly you beat me to even suggesting it. ;) No problem.